# How to convert my excel data into JSON with the appropriate formatting?

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to use my own data set for the mind-gapper motion chart reproduced by Mike Bostock at https://bost.ocks.org/mike/nations/

He uses a JSON data file from https://bost.ocks.org/mike/nations/nations.json

I have a data file having food trends in an excel file and I'm wondering what is the best approach to converting excel file into the appropriate JSON format?

How did Mike originally do this? I presume that he had an excel file originally?

Comment: What is the structure of your spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the structure of the data in your csv, but I use online tools like this one: http://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-json.htm